# Angular 2, using ngClass with conditionals in ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have ngFor loop that displays data, and based on if something is true or false in that loop, how can I change css? What I tried, does not work for me.

HTML

```
<div class="class" *ngFor="let something of something" [ngClass]="{'classno2': sent}">
    <div> {{something.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

TypeScript

```
something;

this.something = [
    {name: "NAMEE", sent: false},
    {name: "NAMEE2", sent: true},
]
```

CSS

```
.class {
    color: red;
}
.classno2 {
    color: blue;
}
```

I get no errors, but yet nothing changes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [ngClass] like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let some of something" [ngClass]="{'classno2': some.sent, 'class': !some.sent}">
    <div> {{some.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Above will take care of styling based on whether `sent` is true/false.

Working plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/45regTAQvbCu61kvUAlJ?p=preview

Answer (score 5):

Correct syntax :

```
<div class="class" *ngFor="let smth of something" [class.classno2]="smth.sent">
    <div> {{something.name}} </div>
</div>
```